# Redirecting to a new page in Asp.Net with several thechniques - what will happen to the thread you were running it in the prev. page?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, thread-safety

I know there is several ways to change the current page in ASP.Net.
So, by Redirecting to a new page, what will happen to the thread we were running it in the prev. page?

Answer (score 2):

The `Response.Redirect` method uses an exception to exit out of the current page creation cycle, and sends a redirection page back in the response to the browser. The thread then finishes off the `Page` object and returns to the pool just like when a regular page is complete. The browser handles the redirection page and sends a new request to the server, so the redirected page is a completely new request that has no direct relation to the first request.

The `Server.Transfer` method will end the current page execution and continue with the target page without doing a round trip to the server.

The `Server.Execute` method will execute the target page, then return to continue the rest of the code in the original page.

Comment: +1 for your great answer, but could you please explain more about "The thread then finishes off the Page object and returns to the pool just like when a regular page is complete" ? 
by the way, "round trip" phrase in web applications means sending data to server and client. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It will be returned to the ASP.NET thread pool.

Comment: I have faced an issue in this regards. I need to redirect to specific error state. Hence I do Server.Redirect. But Since I stop the current thread while doing that, an exception occurs & page goes to generic error page. Exception is Current thread aborted. As a workaround, I let the current thread complete. BUt I feel its a waste of Comp resources. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ganesh R:Could you show us your code, maybe in a separate post?

Comment: Posted it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185031/cannot-transfer-request-to-desired-asp-net-error-page